# Can i read .msg file and its embedded image using outlook 2003 interop

Tags: c#, outlook-2003

I want to **read attachments and embedded images** of an **.msg file** by loading it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 2003 in C#. Basically I want to read the email and then forward these images as an email as you normally forward an email in Outlook you get all the images that email have. I have found article of reading attachment using Office 2007 and onwards but i have Outlook 2003. So i want to know how can i do it in Outlook 2003 using Interop?

Comment: Is a C# pop3 client an option? with this library http://hpop.sourceforge.net/ or do you already have your mail in outlook and not anymore on the server? or maybe this link will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this Microsoft link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167(v=vs.71).aspx

After you have reference from your desired message, you can extract the image. you can either create a message and attach the image using Outlook interop or use System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to send and email with attachment.

Hope this helps.